# Check whether file exists in Google Drive by using trigger file IDs

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, triggers

I capture file ids from triggers and check whether file exists in drive by. The below script throws exception and terminates the scripts abruptly if any of the trigger associated file is missing or if it is trash as mentioned in the Apps script openById documentation (which is natural). How do I overcome this?

```
function getForms() {
    try {
        var formsList = [];
        var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
        for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
            var fid = triggers[i].getTriggerSourceId();
            if (fid) {
                var title = FormApp.openById(fid).getTitle() == "" ? "Untitled" : FormApp.openById(fid).getTitle();
                formsList.push([title, fid]);
            }
        }
        return formsList;
    } catch (e) {
        ;//catch errors
    }
}
```

Comment: What exception/error are you receiving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `try` `catch` statement wisely to avoid the `Exception`:

```
try {
     if (fid) {
            var title = FormApp.openById(fid).getTitle() == "" ? "Untitled" : FormApp.openById(fid).getTitle();
            formsList.push([title, fid]);
        }
  } catch (e) {
    Logger.log(e.message);
  }
```

Use try catch inside for loop instead of outside in a useless place